# Firestore String Array Keeps Getting overwritten

Tags: swift

Firestore String Array Keeps Getting overwritten everytime I try to
 add a new value to the array im calling the function updateData and if im not wrong it says in the docs it will update the data but wouldn't update mean that its should make another value in the array for example 0 then 1

```
func addUserToLikeArray(){
    //if(MUser.currentUser() != nil){
if (MUser.currentUser() != nil) {

    FirebaseReferece(.Verses).document(postID).updateData([rUSERHASLIKEDARRAY:[MUser.currentAuthID()]]) { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("succesfully ADDED user TO likeArray")
            }
        }

    } else if(fbMuser.currentTokenuser() != nil){

        FirebaseReferece(.Verses).document(postID).updateData([rUSERHASLIKEDARRAY:[fbMuser.currentTokenID()]]) { (error) in
            if(error != nil){
                 print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                 print("succesfully ADDED user TO likeArray")

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append to an array you should use the following method:

```
let washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC")
washingtonRef.updateData(["regions":FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"])])
```

Here's [a link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_11)!

Comment: yea thank you I ended up solving it after reading documentation now I know about array union and remove